# On the number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $\sigma=(1,2,11)(3,4)(5,6,7,8,9)\in S_{12}$. I am willing to get the number of conjugates of $\sigma$. Clearly if $\tau$ be one such, then it must have the same cycle type. So in other words, we need to search for number of elements of cycle type $[2,3,4]$ in $S_{12}$.

And the number is $\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{5}$.

Please tell me if I made any mistake. Thank you in advance

Comment: You've only counted the number of ways of choosing which numbers go into which cycles.  You must also choose how the numbers are arranged in the cycles.  For example, $(5,6,7,8,9)$ is different from $(5,9,7,8,6)$.

Comment: I am unable to complete the track after following your advise. Can you/ anyone finish this for me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number 
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{5}$$ 
counts the ways to pick numbers that belong to each cycle. We must also specify how the numbers are arranged in the cycle. The number of ways to arrange $k$ numbers is $k!$, but cyclic permutation of an arrangement does not change the $k$-cycle, so since there are $k$ cyclic permutations of $k$ numbers we have (by the orbit-stablizer theorem or otherwise) that the number of distinct arrangements of the elements in a $k$-cycle is 
$$\frac{k!}{k}=(k-1)!$$
We must therefore multiply by $(2-1)!(3-1)!(5-1)!$ to obtain
$$\binom{12}{2}\binom{10}{3}\binom{7}{5}2!4!=7983360$$

Comment: thank you/.But suppose that $\sigma$ has the cycle type [2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4] in $S_{24}$. In this case what to do ? ( mean to ask, in case, the cycle type gets repeated, what to do ?)

Comment: I have found recently a new formula. it says that divide $n!$ by $r$ for each $r$ cycle and then divide the result by $n_r!$ if the number of $r$ cycle be $n_r$. So that gives the formula $\frac{n!}{\prod\limits_r r^{n_r}n_r!}$. By this if $\sigma$ has cycle type [2,2,3,3,4,4] then result is $1389404016000$ whereas using your ans, we have $\frac{1}{2!^3}\binom{18}{2}\binom{16}{2}\binom{14}{3}\binom{11}{3}\binom{8}{4} \binom{4}{4}  (2-1)!^2(3-1)!^2(4-1)!^2=\frac{134008875}{2}$. What mistake have i done ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You do the same thing as in my answer, but since the order of cycles of the same size doesn't matter you divide by $3!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!$ (to handle the permutations of the like-sized cycles).

Comment: Notice you don't have enough binomial coefficients. You should have $3$ for $2$, $2$ for $3$, and $3$ for $4$. Then you multiply by $(2!)^2(3!)^3$, then divide by $2!\cdot (3!)^2$.